# Get the onended event for an AudioBuffer in HTML5/Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-audio-api

So I am playing audio file in Chrome and I want to detect when playing has ended so I can delete references to it. Here is my code

```
var source = context.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = sound.buffer;
source.loop = sound.loop;
source.onended = function() { 
    delete playingSounds[soundName];
}
source.connect(mainNode);
source.start(0, sound.start, sound.length);
```

however, the event handler doesn't fire. Is this not yet supported as described by the [W3 specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html)? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This would probably be a better question for Stackoverflow.com. It's not specifically related to game development. I can move it if you like.

Comment: well, supposedly, it has been fixed, but I can't get it to work. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116798

Answer (score 1):

Chromium only added this recently (end of May, I think). Pretty sure it's not in the stable releases yet.

Have you tried it in Chrome Canary?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is still buggy in Chromium, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=349543 . As an obvious but not always suitable workaround, I suggest setting a timer for the duration of the audio.